# Live time function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have my Agotime function set up. I'm just wondering what method I should use to make my time update live. Many would say Ajax but would this be server heavy? I need a smooth change every 5 seconds.

Also how could I do this?

```
 function Agotime($date)

    {
        if(empty($date)) {
            return "No date provided";
        }

        $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
        $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

        $now             = time();
        $unix_date       = strtotime($date);

           // check validity of date
        if(empty($unix_date)) {    
            return "Bad date";
        }

        // is it future date or past date
        if($now > $unix_date) {    
            $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
            $tense         = "ago";

        } else {
            $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
            $tense         = "from now";
        }

        for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
            $difference /= $lengths[$j];
        }

        $difference = round($difference);

        if($difference != 1) {
            $periods[$j].= "s";
        }

        return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";

    }
```

Comment: If you want to update something on the browser, you should use [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: since you want it every 5 seconds, I'd say `setInterval(callback,5000);` would be perfect: a function will be called every 5000 ms, automatically. assign the returnvalue of `setInterval` to some variable, though: you need it to `clearInterval`

Comment: As long as neither your server nor client are travelling at relativistic speeds, it's safe to assume that time is passing at the same rate for each of them.  Why not just ask the server for the time once at load time and from then repeatedly calculate it on the client, e.g., using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`?

Comment: How would I go about writing this into my function? Help would be appreciated, I'm sure its fairly simple, but never used this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it one of two ways.

You could use AJAX, as you proposed, and query your PHP script for how long ago it was. This could be heavy on the number of requests, however.

You could also implement the function in Javascript, and simply pass include pass the timestamp to the script on load. This way you won't have to do any requests to the server, and could keep the time updated live. This, of course, assumes that the timestamp doesn't change.

I'd personally pick option #2, as it's easily calculated in Javascript, and avoids a lot of network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to pass in an incrementing date, use setTimeout and fire it every 5 seconds

Then if you wanted to you can do a "check" to make sure the time on the server matches what you have in the browser, use an ajax call every X updates to "re-sync" the date/time